# Excel vlookup but different

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two tables. One 'master' data table and one log table (as shown in the screenshots)

Log dataset:

[image: log dataset]

'Master' dataset:

[image]

The result I want is a formula that gives me the email addresses of the people who do not appear in the log dataset.
In this case,the result I want is:

[image]

Does anyone knows the formula to get this result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above answer should work. Here is another alternative that is similar.

[image]

```
=IF(XLOOKUP(D1, B:B, B:B, TRUE) = TRUE, E1, "")
```

If your version of Excel has FILTER(), you could then filer column G into a another column to get list of email addresses without the blank rows, or your can use a filter at the top of Col G.

Answer (score 1):

> The result I want is a formula that gives me the email addresses of the people who do not appear in the log dataset

You can do a same-column `VLOOKUP`, searching for `Name` in `Master` in `Name` in `Log`. Wrap that call in `ISERROR`: when the resulting column is `TRUE`, that means the name does not exist in `Log` (this, of course, assumes no two e-mails share the same name).

Answer (score 0):

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Table4[email],MATCH(1,(COUNTIF(Table2[name],Table4[name])=0)*(COUNTIF($C$15:$C15,Table4[email])=0),0)),"")`

Where Table4 = Master table
Table2 = Log table

Enter the formula with `ctrl+shift+enter`